# How QFileInfo::setCaching(bool enable) works?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to check 10 times if share folder ( samba ) exists. When I run my application, for the first check I have to wait 25 seconds. Checks number 2-10 are very fast ( less than 0.01 second ). So I would like to always wait 25 seconds. I find class `QFileInfo` and method `setCaching`, but it doesn't work, how I expected. Why I still get data about that folder from the cache ( for 2-10 checks )?

```
    QFileInfo fileInfo(R"(\\192.168.200.200\)");
    fileInfo.setCaching(false);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        qInfo()<<fileInfo.exists();
    }
```

I know about method `connectToHost`, but sometimes it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe it's wiser to wait longer then check again. You can always command your program to sleep/wait.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist But how can I check longer? I don't see any ```method``` like ```setTimeoutForExists()```. I think ```sleep``` is not a good solution. If application get info about exists from cache I never get "true".

Comment: You could try to use `refresh` member function, to force it to update cache.

Comment: @Kaldrr I tried in a loop: ```exists```, ```refresh``` and the same result

Comment: Note that the operating system may have its own cache that you have no control over. Other people have asked questions about this in the past. It seems the proper approach is to use a file system watcher instead of repeatedly polling.

Comment: @Botje Do you mean ```ReadDirectoryChangesW``` function?

Comment: @juga92 Responding to the question you asked me, just use something like `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10))`, and this way you sleep 10 seconds then check again. But this is up to your program design, because you may want to do this asynchronously and not block. In other words, the fact that Qt is failing fast doesn't mean there's a caching problem. It might just mean that Qt can figure out a better way after the first time that's faster.